# How to start writing a front end for spring web service

Tags: java, web-services, frontend

I wrote a web service in spring. When I send a soap envelope to it I get a response. Now I need to write some client - front end for this application which creates this soap envelope sends it to this endpoint and processes the response. Can you help me? Where should I start?

UPDATE:

I forgot to write here that I would like to have a web page where there will be some button "send" which creates a soap envelope with parameters and sends them to the endpoint.

Comment: Use Struts framework and start developing jsps

Comment: can you be more concrete ? some tips for good tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the Spring-WS [client-side API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)

Comment: sorry but I didnt find here how to create some web site

Comment: Oh, wow - that's sort of a bigger question. Like asking "how do I create an application". Well, there are many different technologies for that. Since you are already using Spring, why not continue with Spring MVC (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html). Google around a bit for tutorials on Spring MVC and view technologies like JSP and JSTL.

Comment: yes that is why I ask for some help because I know that there is a lot of possibilities how to create client but I dont know any of them so I need some advice

Comment: Well, look at Spring MVC and jsp/jstl. Search around the web for tutorials and then try it out.

Comment: hm I dont think this is what I looking for. I didnt find how to create soap envelope and send this to my endpoint

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391428/spring-web-service-client-tutorial-or-example-required

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools available in many languages which automatically create soapClient using WSDL file.I ues eclipse IDE (Indigo EE).This provide you facility to create soapClient in java by using WSDL file.

Comment: I personally recommend REST Web service over SOAP service due to flexibility and lightweight.

Comment: ecplipse IDE is just IDE. where I programming this project. I looking for some framework which I can use

Comment: Hey eclipse has built-in tool for creating soapclient. If you download eclipse enterprise edition you can find File->New->Others->Web Service->Web service Client... 
You only need to specify the location of your WSDL file .. eclipse automatically generate Soapclient.

I hope you have created WSDL file already... :)

Comment: yes I have and I try this but I think this isnt what I looking for. In generated file I didnt found any view tier

Comment: I didn't get your view tier mean.