# Integration of a web application with a third party application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, eai

I am developing an integration solution where my web application has to communicate with a third party application. Web application can call the services of the third party application only by calling its executable with specific parameters. Third party application then produces results in form of files that are stored on the server where it is installed. These files are to be used and processed by the web application. The web application and the third party application will not necessarily be on the same servers. The web application is built with Spring framework.

At the moment I am trying to search for the best methodologies and best practices that should be used to perform this integration. Since I am new to this area I do not know the exact terminologies that I should use to search for. I also do not know the exact term that describes such a setting where a web application is integrated with such a third party application.

I need some guidance about what kind of information to search for and what terminologies to use during the search. This is important for me because I also need to document to whole search process and the solution based on current methodologies and best practices.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Asma

Comment: Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - you should provide us with examples of research you have already done in trying to answer the question yourself. Then provide specific issues/questions you have regarding the possible solutions you have identified. Lastly, you need to provide more details about your server app: what form do the files take (plain text, XML, etc), what is the software running on the server (Java, C, etc) and does it provide a REST or SOAP API, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Spring Web-Service client APIs, see below links help you to find an approach.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html

[Spring Web Service Client Tutorial or Example Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391428/spring-web-service-client-tutorial-or-example-required)